# Bootstrap toggle switch: Show modal on click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

I am using [Bootstrap Switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/) with a simple on/off option.
How do I show a Bootstrap Modal asking for a confirmation once the user changes from `on` to `off` or from `off` to `on`?

**Example 1** - User clicks to switch `on`.
**Modal:** `Are you sure you want to switch on?`

**Example 2** - User clicks to switch `off`.
**Modal:** `Are you sure you want to switch off?`

I am able to set the modal on this **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/nn6dU/21/)** but it's not working if the user clicks straight on the blue or gray color.

```
<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#showModal">
    Change status:
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch" checked />
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="showModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is the modal
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nn6dU/23/) Fiddle if it works for you.

Comment: @Patel same issue. Click exactly on the on (blue area) or the off (grey area) it wouldn't work. check my fix in the answers

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast Ah right, I thought problem was with displaying dynamic modal body on clicks. I didn't pay attention to area where I am clicking.. LOL.. Good on you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder why this issue. But I succeeded in creating a fix to your issue. Basically instead of allowing the div to target, you can listen to the switch event and use bootstrap's modal show/hide functions to show or hide your modal.

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0owp23ug/)

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myswitch").bootstrapSwitch();

    $('#myswitch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function (e, data) {
        $('#showModal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    Change status:
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="myswitch" checked />
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="showModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is the modal
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @CodingEnthusiast, I need the same function as this but Im using angularjs. I tried this into my code but it did not work. How can I possibly achieve this using angular?

Comment: @brunodd, Its calling the same modal not for "are you sure to switch off?" and "are you sure to switch on?" did you do it?

Comment: @bleykFaust it's calling two different modals. Basically it's a "Are you sure? Yes/No" modal. I'm not sure how to do it in Angular =(

Comment: @bleykFaust raise a new question, tag me and i will come help. hope you some snippet of your code ready

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast thanks here is the link to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35691225/modal-on-bs-switch-angularjs