# Modal on BS Switch AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

Good day! I'm making a page and I'm using a bs switch. When I switch it on, the modal that is supposed to pop up is already showing. My problem now is that when I switch it off, a different modal should also pop up. I have tried several codes but its not working. Thanks for any help.

This is my html code for the switch:

```
 <div class="switch_button">
    <input type="checkbox"   ng-model="checkbox[$modalArray]" ng-change="modalVolEn($modalArray)" bs-switch />
</div>
```

my controller is :

```
$scope.modalArray = [];
$scope.modalVolEn = function() {
    if($scope.modalArray) {
        $('#showModal').modal('show');
    }
    else{
         $('#showModal2').modal('show');
    }


};
```

and my modals:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="showModal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

---------

<div class="modal fade" id="showModal2" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
```

Comment: Can you create working plunkr for your code?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't @PareshGami . please give me a sample though

Comment: which bootstrap version you are using?

Comment: @PareshGami the concept is the same as this jsfiddle but it is not on angular and it displays the same modal upon switch on and switch off. What I need is a display of different modals http://jsfiddle.net/0owp23ug/

Comment: @PareshGami bootstrap-switch - v3.3.2 is the version i am using

Comment: Short-answer: take a look at "angular UI bootstap" and use it instead of jquery with bootstrap ---- Long-answer: don't mix `jquery` DOM manipulation inside an `angular`'s controller. You will sure have lots of conflict happen if you do it this way. Still it is possible but I do not recommend your setup at this moment.

Comment: @LinhPham, I'm new to angular and certainly I can't easily understand it. Can you give me a sample of how and waht you are saying? if it is not too much of your time. It will be a great help. Thanks

Comment: @bleykFaust Try https://github.com/frapontillo/angular-bootstrap-switch

Comment: @PareshGami I already tried it. I downloaded and run the samples but its not working

Comment: Make your example as live same where with cdn css and js file

Comment: @PareshGami sorry but I didnt get it

Comment: i mean your tried example i want it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104822/discussion-between-bleykfaust-and-paresh-gami).

Comment: @bleykFaust it will took lots of time to explain. It releate with `$scope` cycle. One of the most complex topic when talking about `angular` . That is why I suggest you to use `bootstap UI angular` which is `bootstrap` but it wrote in angular instead of jquery. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal ---- P.S. don't rush to try to understand what is  `$scope`'s cycle so soon. Take your time (this was took me a month to fully understand it)

Comment: @LinhPham yeah but how am i suposed to connect it with bootstrap switch?modals here are connected with a button

Comment: @bleykFaust, you can make a driective and wrap required feature from BS switch (or use the plugin as PareshGami has suggested), then passing value to your controller and in controller you are comunicating with the modals.

Comment: how @LinhPham please guide me

Comment: @bleykFaust, it is fairly complicated and it need at least 2-3 answer. And even lots of code to full fill you needs. I cannot put all the things in a single answer for you. ===> Here is the simplest things you can try now. Integrate `angular UI bootstrap` and `angular bootstrap switch`

Comment: @CodingEnthusiast here is my question hope you can help me more here